# aria-hidden="true" or aria-live="assertive" is not working with foreach in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, aria, dynamic-design-attributes-rendering

I have a requirement where NVDA screen reader should read the error messages (dynamically displayed) on the lwc. I have an array with list of error messages and used  to display them. However these messages are never read by NVDA Speech viewer. I tried adding aria-hidden="true", aria-live="assertive" and role="alert" along with aria-atomic="true" to  tag but none of them working. Unable to find the issue, can anyone please help? Here is the code:

```
                <ul aria-live="assertive">
                <template for:each={Errors} for:item="err">
                    <li class="slds-text-align--right" key={err}>{err}</li>
                </template></ul>

                <ul role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
                <template for:each={Errors} for:item="err">
                    <li class="slds-text-align--right" key={err}>{err}</li>
                </template></ul>
```